# Need help placing a border at top and bottom of navbar

Tags: html, css, border, navbar

Ive tried for hours to get a border at the top and bottom of my navbar. 
http://www.rubricdesign.co.uk/  http://www.rubricdesign.co.uk/style.css

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong? Please include relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: You have made one heck of a weird navbar

Comment: Well when ever I add a border top and bottom it appears above the navbar

Comment: @MathewSefton thats because the navbar is not around the div which is because of how you made it

Comment: I will add a border top and bottom and show you the error

Comment: have a look now, that's as far as I get and you can see it not the dessired effect lol

Comment: Your font is too big for the container. See my answer below with the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `font-size` is too big for the `<nav>`. That's what's happening. Plus all the unnecessary floats. Here's a link to get you back to the start and you can style from here: http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/ypL8n/1/

Comment: Thank you.  I will get the hang of this eventually lol

Answer (score 1):

use css:

```
#navi {
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

CSS

```
border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
```

So it's border-top: ( thickness )  ( type of line ) ( color )

Answer (score 0):

use css:

```
.navbar {
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

Also you have given it a set height remove that